# How to render with solid colors on each face?

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting

I'm trying to get a retro 3d look with unsmoothed lowpoly faces.

It's pretty close, but i want every face to only be a single color (as determined by the average color based on the render)

[image]

As you can see there's a lot of gradients around the blue, and some blurring on the edges of some reds.

example of what I want: [image]

I know I could do this with the compositor by applying a color ramp set to constant, but that would be unable to account for the blue lighting.

I would also like to animate this, so I would be unable to bake it into a texture map.

Comment: I'd say you have to resign from a shader, and calculate color based on normal and camera vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is obtained with a Diffuse shader with roughness = 1:

[image: cycles test]

Though you need to disable Cycles global illumination in order to not have light bouncing everywhere and lighting things up indirectly:

[image: disable GI]

You can also obtain this with eevee:

[image: eevee test]

All I did was to enable Ambient Occlusion, set distance to zero and set a higher strenght (you need to write it, Blender soft locks it at 1 otherwise):

[image: add AO]

And here's the workbench:

[image: workbench test]

The workbench is basically what you have in solid view. It does have some several downsides, like being unable to use your scene's light and actual shaders. But it's also really close technology to your reference and you do have some flexibility and some options you don't have out of the box with other render engines:

[image: workbench settings]

Comment: that does seem to work so I may have to do that, but i was hoping i could still control the roughness

Comment: Well I think there's a way to get something even closer by playing with normals texture coordinaites, but I don't have access to Blender right now so I will have to come back on this topic later today

Comment: Also, do you need to render on Eevee/Cycles specifically? Because i think it would be also way easier to get such result using the Workbench engine. Tell me and I adapt my answer as needed.

Comment: Ive never used workbench, but am open to the possibilities if it ends up looking closer to my target. im using eevee above

Comment: Basically you want to emulate old game's style, right? I'll look into this after work ;)

Comment: im not trying to emulate it exactly, just the flat colored faces part. i think nathan figured out most of the kinks the way I was doing it, but I'm always open to more methods which might be easier / more accurate. I'm hoping to create something to add to a free blender toolkit

Comment: I edited my answer with new informations. and pictures ♥

Answer (score 1):

You will get almost the entire way to your goal pic by tuning down rendering settings and using a Diffuse shader in Eevee:

[image]

I've reduced the radius of every light to 0.0, I've disabled soft shadows (and other settings like screen space reflections, ambient occlusion, and bloom), and I've told the flat-shaded sphere to just use a 0.0 roughness diffuse.

Note also that there are no true shadows in your goal pic.  You will probably want to disable shadows on all materials.  If you need the ground shadows, probably the easiest way to capture them is via shadow catcher techniques.  (In the game, these ground shadows are made by projecting the mesh onto the ground plane and only onto the ground plane-- it's very similar to how the meshes are projected onto your camera's near clip plane to draw the whole scene.)

Now, if we look carefully at the sphere I made, we're going to see that there is some very small difference in color across the face.  This is because I'm using point lights, and so the direction to each sample varies slightly-- very slightly.  In your game pic, the only lighting is from a "sun" lamp (maybe a pair-- the lighting appears to be coming from a different direction than the ground shadows point.)  If you use only sun lamps in your own render, you won't see any variation across each face.  (Or, if you put your point lights very far away, the variation will become less and less.)  If point lights were implemented in this engine, they would probably also have small variation across faces.

Notice something else from your goal pic: a *lot* of the lighting is ambient lighting.  More ambient lighting than you have in your first pic.  You can create ambient lighting in Eevee just by using a world with a flat color; if already doing that, you can make the world brighter in its shader nodes.